# Вывести слова в которых каждая буква слова встречается 2 или более раза

Tags: c++, строки

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    SetConsoleCP(1251); 
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    // перекодировка
    char string[50];
    int i, j, n = 1;
    char c;
    bool f = false;
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Введите строку" << " ";
    gets_s(string);
    cout << "Ваша строка" << " " <<  string << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string - 1 ); i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < strlen(string); j++) {

            if (string[i] == ' ' ) {
                break; // Если строка пустая то выход из цикла
            }
            if (string[i] == string[j]) {
                n++;

            }
            if (n >= 2) {
                cout << "Имеет два или более символов" << endl;
                cout << string[i] << endl;

            }
            n = 1;


            }
        }
    }
```

Дана непустая последовательность слов, разделенная пробелами( одним или несколькими), за последним -точка. Слово-это любая последовательность символов до разделителя.

Вывести слова в которых каждая буква слова встречается 2 или более раза. Если таких слов нет, то вывести соответствующее сообщение
Как вывести слова? У меня получилось вывеси символы которые встречаются 2 или более раза!

Comment: Всмысле, как вывести слова? Берете std::cout и выводите их как строки - вот и все

Comment: Бешеный двойной цикл непонятно зачем. 1 раз прости и заполнить unordered_map<char, size_t> count_map; "strlen(string - 1 )" и как оно не крашнулось...